# Trying to add ng2-redux in my angular4 project

Tags: angular, redux

This is my package.json.

```
{
  "name": "try",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-redux/store": "^6.5.7",
    "@angular/animations": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "ng-redux": "^3.5.0",
    "ng2-redux": "^5.1.2",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.45",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "redux-devtools": "^3.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~3.0.4",
    "tslint": "~5.3.2",
    "typescript": "~2.3.3"
  }
}
```

when i run it as `npm install` it gives me following warnings and also the redux libraries does not get included in node modules.

> npm WARN angular2@2.0.0-beta.21 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6
>   but none was installed.    npm WARN angular2@2.0.0-beta.21 requires a
>   peer of zone.js@^0.6.12 but     none was installed.    npm WARN
>   ng2-redux@5.1.2 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.4.0 but     none
>   was installed.
>
> npm WARN redux-devtools@3.4.0 requires a peer of react@^0.14.9 ||
>   ^15.3.0 but none was installed.    npm WARN redux-devtools@3.4.0
>   requires a peer of react-redux@^4.0.0 ||     ^5.0.0 but none was
>   installed.